# How to get this recursive function in scheme to return true

Tags: recursion, set, scheme

My function `element?` is supposed to take a set `S` (a list whose order doesn't matter) and an element `e` and then returns `#t` if the element is in the set, or `#f` if the element is not in the set. All of my test cases work, except for this one:

`(element? '("a" "b" "c") "ab")`

It seems to not return anything, but I have no clue why. I went through the debugger to try and figure it out, but I can't figure it out because it just exits the function without returning anything. The following is my code:

```
(define (element? S e)
  
  (cond [(null? S) #F]
        [(equal? (car S) e) #T]
        [(element? (cdr S) e)]
        ))
```

Any thoughts? I must be missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Do other cases where the element is not found work?

Comment: No, they do not. However, when the list is empty, it returns #F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last cond clause to use `else` as the condition.

```
(define (element? S e)
  
  (cond [(null? S) #F]
        [(equal? (car S) e) #T]
        [else (element? (cdr S) e)]
        ))
```

When a clause consists just of a condition, the value of the condition is returned if it's not `#f`. If it's `#f`, `cond` continues with the following tests. In this case, there are no remaining tests, so it returns nothing (the language specification says the result is undefined). Use `else` as the last condition to ensure that you return the value of the recursive call whatever it is.

So your code returns `#t` when the recursion returns `#t`, but doesn't return anything when it returns `#f`.